# Estimating the ratio of two successive Telephone numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $(T_n)$ be the sequence of [Telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_(mathematics))(recall that $ T_0 = T_1 = 1, \ T_{n+1} = T_{n} + nT_{n-1},\ n\ge 1$). Is it true that 
for any $n\geq 10$,
$$
\lfloor \bigg(\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_{n}}\bigg)^2 \rfloor =n+1+\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor \tag{1}
$$

(where as usual $\lfloor \ \rfloor$ denotes the "floor" integer part) I have checked this up to $n=25000$. I encountered (1) while working on a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147294/how-to-prove-this-conjecture-x-nn-ge-4-cant-be-an-integer)